# Downloading file to "/public" directory using Meteor/Cordova iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, meteor

I'm building an iOS app similar to the Lynda.com app that allows you to download videos to your device for offline viewing.

I can't seem to figure out how to download to and access files from the public directory. I'm using [org.cordova.apache.file](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.file) and [org.cordova.apache.file-system](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.file-transfer) to download files to the device, but Meteor cannot access them. So I thought that maybe if I could get these files to download to the "/public" directory, I'd have more luck.

The problem I'm having specifically is that whenever I do

```
meteor run ios-device
```

The "version" property of this object

```
Meteor.connection._mongo_livedata_collections.meteor_autoupdate_clientVersions._docs._map['version-cordova'].version
```

gets updated.

I need that property to append to the directory path I get when I console.log cordova.file.dataDirectory. The property however shows as undefined when I try to use it in a variable. I can clearly see it when I console.log but I can't use it in a var.

Is

```
Meteor.connection._mongo_livedata_collections.meteor_autoupdate_clientVersions._docs._map['version-cordova'].version
```

A private/protected variable? How can I access it? If I can figure this out I'm seriously considering posting a video tutorial since a lot of people seem to want to know how to do this.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this and do that video tutorial? Stuck on this right now

Comment: @cupcakekid Don't have a working solution just yet but I found a potential solution in the form of the [CorHttpd](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.rjfun.cordova.httpd) cordova plugin. I'm working with it right now and received some help via Twitter so I'll probably be answering this question soon and creating a video tutorial after I finish this project.

Comment: @Optymystyc Any luck with this? Really hoping you got this figured out! :)